# Getting a syntax error on a comment? Or am I missing something obvious?

Tags: php, html, syntax

I am writing a report form but I am this really weird syntax error.

Here is my code:

```
<h2>Report <u><?php echo $title; ?></u> Machine Program Error</h2>
<p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
<form action="send_form_email.php?email=yes"> 
   Job Number: <input type="text" name="jobid" value="<?php print ($jobid) ?>">
   <!--<span class="error">* <?phpecho $nameErr;?></span>-->
   <br><br>
   Part Number: <input type="text" name="partid" value="<?php print ($part_id) ?>">
   <!--<span class="error">* <?phpecho $emailErr;?></span>-->
   <br><br>
   Machine: <input type="text" name="mach" value="<?php print ($machCode) ?>">
   <!--<span class="error">* <?phpecho $machErr;?></span>-->
   <br><br>
   Note: <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40" placeholder="More detail... (Is there a way to recreate the error?)"><?php echo $comment;?></textarea>
   <br><br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>
```

Lines with the comments; `<!--<span class="error">* <?phpecho $nameErr;?></span>-->`, `<!--<span class="error">* <?phpecho $emailErr;?></span>-->`, and `<!--<span class="error">* <?phpecho $machErr;?></span>-->` are pulling up syntax errors.

Am I missing something obvious or is there and error with my Dreamweaver CS5? If one of the two is true, how do I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should put a space between `<?php` and `echo`

Comment: @YazanWYusuf But wouldn't that activate the php even though I want it commented out?

Comment: you can't comment out php with `<-- ->` since they're used to comment html only.  to comment php statements you have to add `//` for a single line and `/* */` for multi lines.

Comment: It seems to work. thanks! Kind of annoying though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML comments have no effect on PHP. You also have a syntax error

Try this:

```
<h2>Report <u><?php echo $title; ?></u> Machine Program Error</h2>
<p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
<form action="send_form_email.php?email=yes"> 
   Job Number: <input type="text" name="jobid" value="<?php print ($jobid) ?>">
   <!--<span class="error">* <?php //echo $nameErr;?></span>-->
   <br><br>
   Part Number: <input type="text" name="partid" value="<?php print ($part_id) ?>">
   <!--<span class="error">* <?php //echo $emailErr;?></span>-->
   <br><br>
   Machine: <input type="text" name="mach" value="<?php print ($machCode) ?>">
   <!--<span class="error">* <?php //echo $machErr;?></span>-->
   <br><br>
   Note: <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40" placeholder="More detail... (Is there a way to recreate the error?)"><?php echo $comment;?></textarea>
   <br><br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>
```